# How do I set a border on a div that wraps a checkbox?

Tags: css

I am trying to create a div the dimensions of which are exactly the same as those of a checkbox. When I specify something like this

```
<html>
    <head>
         <style type="text/css">
             .wrapper {
                 margin: 12px;
                 width: 13px;
                 height: 13px;
                 border: 1px solid green;
                 display: inline-block;
             }
         </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper"><input type="checkbox" /></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get a small top margin between the green border and the checkbox in both Chrome and Firefox. If I reduce the height of the div, it raises the lower boundary of the div without affecting the top. I've tried playing with the margin on the checkbox but that did not affect the gap.

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gene/hpZqK/) that shows this behavior.

Thanks,

Gene

Comment: By the way, there's no need to set `width: 13px; height: 13px;` (unless you need it to make sure things fit in your layout). `display: inline-block` on `.wrapper` means it will automatically fit to the `input`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `display: block` on `.wrapper input`: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/hpZqK/5/

Or, set `line-height: 0` on `.wrapper`: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/hpZqK/6/

You need to do this because `input` is treated as `inline-block`.

Comment: This is it. I was just about to post this.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I want to change the `display` property to block; the `line-height` solution works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Hacky fix - give the checkbox -2px of `top`: http://jsfiddle.net/hpZqK/4/

Comment: ok, that works. But I'd like to know why this is needed... thoughts?

Comment: This doesn't really work, and as you said, is kinda hacky. @thirtydot solution is the way to go.

Comment: I disagree, it does really work, have a gander at the fiddle :P It's undoubtedly a hack though, and thirty's is the cleaner solution.

Comment: This does sort of work, but it's dependent on `line-height` (and `font-size`). For instance, setting `body { line-height: 2; }` breaks it: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/hpZqK/8/.